# Can I omit 'to be' in "I consider him to be the best"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> **I consider him to be the best.**

My question is if we can remove 'to be' from the sentence without the meaning being changed
:***I consider him the best***.

If the meaning remains same then why are their structures different? Can I remove 'to be' from any other sentences and the meaning will be unchanged?

Comment: Yes, you can omit the words _to be_. They are said to be 'understood' - the listener/reader understands the sentence as though they were there.

Comment: Someone else will have to explain why the two structures are both available. In any case, I don't know that I agree that "to be" is "understood" when omitted, per @KateBunting's comment. I view the version without "to be" as an alternative (and, to my taste, better) version, not a shortened version. To answer your final question, you can't generally remove "to be" from a sentence without changing its meaning or causing grammatical or other damage.

Comment: "*Can I remove 'to be' from any other sentences and the meaning will be unchanged?*" — Hamlet, Act 3, Scene 1 would significantly experience a loss of meaning: "*Or not, that is the question. …*".

Answer (score 1):

When you contract "I consider him to be the best" to "I consider him the best" it only retains the same meaning because we can infer your meaning from context (or probability) and there's not many alternate meanings.

For example, "I consider him the best" might actually mean that you are the best at considering him, and that's a more likely interpretation in a sentence like "I consider the meaning of life the best".

You can bolster this ability to infer meaning by being less ambiguous, e.g. "I consider him the best at what he does", but keeping "to be" is a reliable way of removing that ambiguity.

So to answer your questions directly:

> Can I omit 'to be' in "I consider him to be the best"

Yes, with care.

> If the meaning remains same then why are their structures different?

They aren't, you've just skipped part of it.

> Can I remove 'to be' from any other sentences and the meaning will be unchanged?

Yes, but only in the sense that you can remove any number of words from any sentence so long as there's enough left for your reader to understand your meaning given the context, but be aware you're requiring more effort from your readers when you do so.